# Cannot resize UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder, storyboard

I've been searching all week for a way to resize my UITableView. I'm trying to create a UIView that lists "buddies" from AIM. I'm not very far, mostly because I keep getting stuck trying to figure out UITableViews. My final major issue is how the UITableView shows up in my UIView.

**My navigation bar displays perfectly at the top, but the UITableView always appears beneath it, fullscreen, as if the bar isn't there- and I can't change it.** I've tried to implement a ton of different solutions, none of which have worked so far.

Three (of the many) suggestions that I've tried:

> stackoverflow.com/questions/2906449/uitableview-less-than-full-screen-from-code
>
> discussions.apple.com/thread/1761745?start=0&tstart=0
>
> iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18180-resizing-uitableview-programatically.html

Here's some code I thought would work, but didn't, just like most of the stuff with frames that were suggested elsewhere:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[[self view] addSubview:_navigationBar];

UIView *tableViewer = [UIView new];
[tableViewer addSubview:_buddiesTable];
[tableViewer setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];

[[self view] addSubview:tableViewer];
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

I'm not sure what else to supply for help; if anyone needs more material to help solve my problem, feel free to ask.

[A screenshot from the problem in action.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rhlw.png)

[A screenshot from the StoryBoard of the table in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0RYR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the size manually within the Storyboard File and let me know how it goes. I encountered this a while ago while I was designing an app for a client.

FYI, Storyboard makes iPhone Development theoretically easier, though sometimes explicit IB use is best. :)

EDIT: I spot a problem above; Why are you creating a UIView of frame "0,0,50,50"? It may help to:

```
UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
[theView addSubview:buddiesTable];
//etc...
```